# Filtering displayed data based on the data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an input field and a bunch of containers that contain multiple `data` attributes, how do I dynamically show/hide the containers based on the value of the input? For example, if the value of the search input is "frontend" it should only display containers that have `data-role: frontend`, the same goes for the rest.

```html
<input type="search">

    <div class="container" data-role="Fullstack" data-level="Midweight" data-languages="JavaScript Rub" data-tools="Sass">

     <div></div>

    </div>

    <div class="container" data-role="Backend" data-level="Junior" data-languages="Ruby" data-tools="RoR">

     <div></div>

    </div>
```

I'd like it to be in jQuery.

Comment: You should add the code you've attempted to the question as an [mcve]. This isn't a free coding site. We help with problems with code you've already written. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

First make all of them hidden, for instance with visibility property of css then on input's blur/change call a function like this

```js
$('div[id^=proto_]').filter('div[data-role=frontend]').css('visibility','visible');
```

Also you need to add an id to all of the elements the get them. in my example I added some id's starting with `proto_`.